# How to use data processed in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sharepoint, backgroundworker

I am writing a Winform application. It will query data from Sharepoint 2010 using the client object model, and do some charts based on some selections.

My problem is: I want the program to load the data from Sharepoint using a background worker. Once the background worker is completed, I want it to populate some ListBoxes with some of the results.

I cant do it, as

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'EngineerAccountBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

It fails where I want to do the **ListBox.Items.Add.**

I've never written a backgroundoworker (or winform app for that matter) before, please help!

Code:

```
        public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {


        string siteUrl = "http://myurl.com";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MCS Assignment");

        var Yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        var RightNow = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

        string query = "<View><Query><Where>" +
                "<And>" +      
                        "<Geq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value></Geq>" +
                        "<Leq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Leq>" +
                "</And>" +
        "</Where></Query><RowLimit></RowLimit></View>";

        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format(query, Yesterday, RightNow);
        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (ListItem li in collListItem)
        {
            FieldUserValue usv = li["EngineerAccount"] as FieldUserValue;

            **EngineerAccountBox.Items.Add(usv.LookupValue);**
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DONE");           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a cross thread invoker.

It should be like this: (Note that it is just a sample, probably it wont work in your code, i do not know the type of "LookupValue" so customize that by your requirements)

```
void AddToEngineerAccountBox(LookupValue value)
{
    if(EngineerAccountBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        EngineerAccountBox.Invoke((Action<LookupValue>)AddToEngineerAccountBox, value);
        return;
    }

    EngineerAccountBox.Items.Add(value);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

@HenkHolterman realized a good point.

use this instead above

```
void AddToEngineerAccountBox(LookupValue[] value)
{
    if (EngineerAccountBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        EngineerAccountBox.Invoke((Action<LookupValue[]>)AddToEngineerAccountBox, value);
        return;
    }

    EngineerAccountBox.Items.AddRange(value);
}
```

and call that function like

```
    AddToEngineerAccountBox(
        collListItem
        .Select(_ => _["EngineerAccount"])
        .OfType<FieldUserValue>()
        .Select(_ => _.LookupValue).
            ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I still need to learn a lot... I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the BackgroundWoker details at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In Short,
BackgroundWorker is used to do the "time-consuming" work on non-UI thread (which is a background thread taken from Threadpool).

Why? because if you do all the work on UI thread then it's going to block UI thread queue which would essentially cause UI to freeze/delay user actions.

What's the big deal about BgWorker Thread, why not just use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?
Because you can not update UI controls from non-UI thread (which is why you are getting the exception mentioned about) directly. In such case, you need to explicitly marshal control update operations to UI thread using Control.Invoke/Control.BeginInvoke.

BackgroundWorker thread does little more than just spawning a thread from threadpool. It provided wrapped in handlers which are called on different threads.
It calls following handlers on UI thread:

```
ProgressChanged
RunWorkerCompleted
```

and "`DoWork`" (the one you are using) on non-UI thread.

Which means, you are not supposed to update UI controls in "DoWork" handler. if you want to do that, you should be using "Control.BeginInvoke", so as to marshal such updates to UI thread.

With this much details, I would suggest to make "right" use of BgWorker object and not do any UI updates on "DoWork". You can call ReportProgress from DoWork, which will call "RunWorkerCompleted" handler (On UI thread) for you to update UI controls.

Comment: Hi Amby, you are more than right, I do need to learn a lot still. I've just started to program back in December 2013, and so far I only wrote apps that run on schedule and query data, compute something, and send emails. (Some of them are kinda cool :) )

But, winforms and multithreading.... I'm in way over my head right now. But I need a GUI program... 

By the way, off-topic, if you have the time: would I be able to do this using WPF? I see there are a lot prettier solutions in WPF than Winforms.

Comment: There is nothing that you can do in WinForm and not in WPF. WPF is a leap ahead but there is a steep learning curve, requires individual cost-benefit analysis.